# Chunking up a 3D array with periodic boundary conditions into subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have a 3D numpy array of shape [N,N,N]. I want to split it into subcubes of size [n,n,n] and store them in an array of shape [N_subcubes, n, n, n, 1]. I also would like each subcube to overlap the previous one by half of its volume.

I have a version of a function that accomplishes this for grids and subcubes that divide evenly, i.e. N = 512 and n = 128. However, if the subcube grid size does not divide evenly into the grid size, such as N = 624 and n = 128, this function does not work.

The nature of the data is periodic, so if the subcube in question spans that boundary, I want the subcube to include entries from the other side of the array.

I also need a corresponding function that would reconstruct the original array from an array of subcubes of the aforementioned shape.

Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What you want sounds a bit like `lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`, which is a easier-to-use version of `as_strided`.   However your periodic extension doesn't work.  But one way of dealing with periodicity is to pad the array with a portion of the 'other side'.  It's easier to visualize that with 1d, or even 2d arrays.  SWV does size 1 offset in each dimension, but bigger offsets can be selected with `::n` indexing.

Comment: Are you sure you want the overlap to be half the *volume* and not half the side?